# Node error: Cannot find module './clone.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I'm working on app using node and postgresql. Recently I updated nodemon and started getting an error when I start my nodemon server: Cannot find module './clone.js'. Here is the code of the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './clone.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:4:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

I checked that on Github and it said that this is recent bug and it was supposed to be fixed with next update. I waited until the update but still had the same error. I reinstalled nodemon, removed node_modules and did `npm install`. Somebody in Github issue page was suggesting to put clone.js in files array which is fine already. graceful-fs.js starts with code:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var polyfills = require('./polyfills.js')
var legacy = require('./legacy-streams.js')
var clone = require('./clone.js')
```

In the same folder there is already file clone.js with content, so now I'm really confused. Please help

[image: file structure of my app]

Comment: can you give us your file structure ?

Comment: @DakshMiglani should I do the screenshot?

Comment: Sure. should work.

Comment: yeah, so it's justified there's no clone.js file in the server directory.

Comment: @DakshMiglani I'm sorry I don't understand why there should be clone.js in server directory?

Comment: What command did u run to update nodemon?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa npm i nodemon@0.5.4

Comment: U need to add the global flag, ie. npm i -g nodemon@0.5.4

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa it didn't work, so I did npm uninstall -g nodemon and then npm install -g nodemon, then it worked. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As somebody mentioned in the comment, I had to update it globally.
So that's what I did to fix it:

npm uninstall -g nodemon

npm install -g nodemon

And then it worked!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and I resolved my issue by running below command.

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```